# Error “Invalid crypto padding” al usar un jwt desde RoR en Flask

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, flask, jwt

Tengo un caso singular. Por diferentes razones, necesito usar un JWT generado por una app en Ruby on Rails, en otra app en Flask (Python), con [Flask-JWT-Extended](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/).

**- EDITO:**

Ahora sé que el token se genera por la librería Devise (cierto?), en un método mágico `sign_in` (no sé mucho sobre Ruby y RoR).

Este método mágico (para mi) genera un token tal que así:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo2MSwiZXhwIjoxNTg3MjIyMjQ5fQ.KcqNDwNjkTPD6rKgTMrt2lw9Swso6gRvLhPq-QvfA6Q}
```

En Python tengo una configuración normal para Flask-JWT-Extended. El Config es:

```py
class Config(object):
    JWT_AUTH_USERNAME_KEY = 'user_id'
    JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX = 'Bearer'
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
    JWT_IDENTITY_CLAIM = 'user_id'
```

Pero, cuando uso el token para llamar a la app en Flask, esta responde con un error:

```
{
    "msg": "Invalid crypto padding"
}
```

Tengo la misma secret key en ambas aplicaciones.

No sé mucho de Ruby, y no sé que está sucediendo.

Gracias de antemano.

---

No sé el motivo ciertamente, solo sé que si borro el último caracter `}` del token, este me funciona también en python...